# How to translate NSLocationTemporaryUsageDescriptionDictionary (iOS 14) strings?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, ios14

I want to show the user the location permission alert when we need their precise location on iOS 14 with a localised purpose string.
According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/3600217-requesttemporaryfullaccuracyauth) you need to have a InfoPlist.strings file with the same key you provide in your plist file like so:

```
<key>NSLocationTemporaryUsageDescriptionDictionary</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Purpose1</key>
        <string>Purpose1Localized</string>
    </dict>
```

And in your InfoPlist.strings file:

```
"Purpose1Localized" = "We need your precise location for....";
```

But this isn't working for me on Xcode 12 beta 6. Does anyone know if this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use the key of the option in the strings file.
"Purpose1" = "We need your precise location for....";

Comment: No need to wrap the key in parenthesis: `Purpose1 = "We need your precise location for....";` works fine.

Comment: @Antonio you are correct that in this specific case there is no need but in manay cases the key developer use has spaces hence the parenthesis.